# Highcharts Highstock How do I change the label on top of tooltip for OHLC series data?

Tags: highcharts, label, tooltip

**Problem**

Run the snippet below in Firefox browser and the top tooltip label is "open". How does one replace the top tooltip label "open" with the new label "Adjusted"?

This is the csv data in the original snippet code:

```
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,open,high,low,close
2006-05-20, 63.26, 64.88, 62.82, 64.51
2006-05-22, 63.87, 63.99, 62.77, 63.38
</pre>
```

**Forced Solution**

In the code snippet I can force the desired result by replacing the CSV header "open" with the name "Adjust" as shown below:

```
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,Adjust,high,low,close
2006-05-20, 63.26, 64.88, 62.82, 64.51
2006-05-22, 63.87, 63.99, 62.77, 63.38
</pre>
```

However I prefer to change the name in the tooltip rather than to change the header in the CSV so I do not regard this as an approved solution.

**Snippet**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
  AAPL Combined OHLC and Moving Average
</title>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,open,high,low,close
2006-05-20, 63.26, 64.88, 62.82, 64.51
2006-05-22, 63.87, 63.99, 62.77, 63.38
2006-05-23, 64.86, 65.19, 63.00, 63.15
2006-05-24, 62.99, 63.65, 61.56, 63.34
2006-05-25, 64.26, 64.45, 63.29, 64.33
2006-05-26, 64.31, 64.56, 63.14, 63.55
2006-05-30, 63.29, 63.30, 61.22, 61.22
2006-05-31, 61.76, 61.79, 58.69, 59.77
</pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 2
    },
    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold: 0
        },
        ohlc: {
            color: 'black',
            tooltip: {
              // pointFormat: 'Adjusted'
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        seriesMapping: [{
            x: 0,
            open: 1,
            high: 2,
            low: 3,
            close: 4
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'ohlc', // bars
        visible: true,
        // set color in plotOptions
        tooltip: {
            // pointFormat: 'Adjusted'
        }
    }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

IF I uncomment either or both pointFormat statements (in the tooltip options shown above) THEN the Open, High, Low, and Close data no longer display in the tooltip pop-up. Instead only the word "Adjusted" appears in the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set name for the series, disable `firstRowAsNames` property and set `startRow` to 1 in data options:

```
    data: {
        firstRowAsNames: false,
        startRow: 1,
        ...
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Adjust',
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fkh0oa2s/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/data

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.ohlc.data